# PHP error reporting is not displaying

Tags: php, lamp

I've appended these in my php.ini and still can't get any php errors to display

```
display_errors = on
display_startup_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL
html_errors = on
log_errors = on
```

here's a copy of my php.ini
http://pastebin.com/Zf3LBJmQ

This is my first time using SSH to administer a server of any kind, thank you for taking the time to read this

So apprently there's two php.ini files? 
I had to edit this one:

/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Now it works great!

Comment: If you solved the problem, please post the answer for the benefit of others. Welcome to Server Fault!

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart apache after making these changes?
Is your app perhaps using [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set) to override these settings?

Comment: yes i've restarted apache and I've been using just a quick php to make an error of any kind appear like: <?php if(x){ ?> and instead of getting an error in the browser, the page doesn't display at all.

Comment: here's a copy of my .ini file http://pastebin.com/Zf3LBJmQ

Comment: Ah, that explains, you just added some values at the bottom. Those settings are set earlier in the file as well and the first one wins.